# Google Chart format numbers with %

Tags: ruby, google-visualization

I'm trying to show numbers on vAxis in percentage. 
I receive the data range from 0-100. My vAxis should range from 0 to 100 with 20pts intervals.

All that works except that i would like to show the number as 10% or 30%. Using format: '##%' will multiply the numbers by 100, as said on the documents. Is there any easy, efficient way for me to display the numbers as percentage?

```
{
  title: 'VP',

  vAxis: {
          title: 'G %',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, 
          gridlines: {count: 7}, 
          viewWindow: { min: 0, 
                        max: 100, 
                        valueLabelsInterval: 20
                      }
        },

  hAxis: {
          title: 'PD',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, 
          slantedText: true
        },

  pointSize: 4

}
```

So this is what I have already. Pic 1

[image: This is what I have]

if I replace the pointSize: 4 with Series:

series: {

```
          0: {

              lineWidth: 0,

              color: '#ff6600',

              pointSize: 4

           },

           1: { color: '#339999'}

        }
```

Then this is what I get

[image: This is what I want]

And this is what I want. Pic 3
[image: This is easy too]

Answer (score 0):

```
vAxis: {
          title: 'G %',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, 
          gridlines: {count: 7}, 
          viewWindow: { min: 0, 
                        max: 100, 
                        valueLabelsInterval: 20
                      },
          format:'##%',
        },
```

Just added the `vAxis.format` property.

Comment: BrOSs, that'd multiply it by 100. Like I mentioned. (I just added some pics, above)

Comment: @SarahA, I can't see the pictures right now (firewall thing), I'll take a look when arrived to home.